# How to access corporate MSMQ from a non-domain PC?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, message-queue, msmq

I have an MSMQ box at work which my app can access while I am logged into to the domain.

At home, I am VPNed into the domain.  However, the app can't access the queue and get this error: `Access to Message Queuing system is denied`.

My hunch is that it is trying to connect with my home computer credentials. 
Is there a way to tell the MessageQueue class to connect with alternate credentials?  I don't see anything obvious.

Or am I wrong at diagnosing the problem?

Comment: Never tried it but I think you need to impersonate your domain user. At first try running the application as your domain user (shift + right click => run as different user) and see if it works.

Comment: @MarcelN. That works fine, but I need to debug it from Visual Studio.  Don't want to run VS from a different user.